# Get column mean every block on n rows based on condition

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, aggregate, apply

I have this dataframe

```
       r2 distance
1   33.64    67866
2    8.50    77229
3   15.07   109119
4   24.35   142279 
5    7.74   143393
6    8.21   177670
7   12.26   216440
8   12.66   253751
9   26.31   282556
10  39.08   320816
```

I need to calculate the mean of column `r2` for every block of rows where the distance between two values in the column `distance` is equal or less than `100000`.
For this example the desired output would be:

```
  mean_r2 diff_of_distance
1   17.86            75527 ## mean of rows 1 to 5; distance 5 - distance 1
2   13.91            66164 ## mean of rows 2 to 5; distance 5 - distance 2
3   13.84            68551 ## mean of rows 3 to 6; distance 6 - distance 3
4   13.14            74161 ## mean of rows 4 to 7; distance 7 - distance 4
5    9.40            73047 ## mean of rows 5 to 7; distance 7 - distance 5
6   11.04            76081 ## mean of rows 6 to 8; distance 8 - distance 6
```

and so on.

Edit 1: I have more than 100,000 rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing, as you show a mean for rows 2-5, however 77,229 (row 2) is not within 10,000 of 109119 (row 3).

Comment: @AdrianMartin You are right, I meant 100,000. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each value of `distance`, minus this from the values in the `distance` vector and test if the result is less than 100000. This creates a boolean vector which you sum to identify the index at which the distance is greater than 100000 (i.e. bool becomes FALSE). Use this index to identify your block then take the mean of `r2` in each block.

To speed up the code define your vector type and length (to avoid "growing vectors" on each iteration.

```
means <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(df))
rows <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(df))
distance_diff <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(df))

for (i in seq_along(df$distance)) {

  dis_val <- df$distance[i] # the ith distance value
  bools <- (df$distance - dis_val) < 100000 # bool indicating if difference between i and every value in vector is less than 100000
  block_range <- sum(bools)# taking sum of bools identifies the value at which the distance becomes > 100000
  rows[i] <- paste(as.character(i), "-", as.character(block_range)) 
  means[i] <- mean(df$r2[i:block_range]) # take the mean of r2 in the range i to all rows where distance is < 100000
  distance_diff[i] <- df$distance[block_range] - dis_val # minus the distance from the value before distance is > 100000 from i

}

data.frame(mean_r2 = means, rows= rows, diff_of_distance=distance_diff)

     mean_r2    rows diff_of_distance
1  17.860000   1 - 5            75527
2  13.915000   2 - 5            66164
3  13.842500   3 - 6            68551
4  13.140000   4 - 7            74161
5   9.403333   5 - 7            73047
6  11.043333   6 - 8            76081
7  17.076667   7 - 9            66116
8  26.016667  8 - 10            67065
9  32.695000  9 - 10            38260
10 39.080000 10 - 10                0
```

Comment: Thanks for yor code, it is fastest than Jimbou's so I would use this one. I have one more curiosity, how to print the difference in distance from the points selected for calculating the mean? Ie, the first mean is calculated among rows 1 to 5, how to print a new column`distance` with the difference between `distance` of row 5 minus `distance` of row 1? See edited question.Thanks!

Comment: Hi Pietro, I have amended the code above to calculate this distance. To do this we simply minus the distance value before distance becomes > 100000 from the distance value `i` and store the result in a new vector called `distance_diff`

Comment: I also made a small amendment to the code to speed it up a bit. Specifically, it now only calculates the `sum(bools)` once instead of three times. I have also annotated each line in the loop to make it clearer what it going on.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Sorry if that sounded trivial but I am starting right now to learn loops in R.

Comment: No problem, SO is a great way to learn - if you are satisfied with the answer can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# your data
d <- read.table(text="r2 distance
1   33.64    67866
           2    8.50    77229
           3   15.07   109119
           4   24.35   142279 
           5    7.74   143393
           6    8.21   177670
           7   12.26   216440
           8   12.66   253751
           9   26.31   282556
           10  39.08   320816", header=T)

library(tidyverse) #dplyr_0.7.2
d %>%
  mutate(index=1:n()) %>% add row index
  group_by(index) %>% # group by this index
  # calculate difference and find max row where diff < 100000
  mutate(max_row=max(which(.$distance - distance < 100000, arr.ind=T))) %>% 
  # calculate mean
  mutate(mean_r2=mean(.$r2[index:max_row])) %>% 
  # calculate the difference
  mutate(diff_of_distance=.$distance[max_row] - .$distance[index]) %>% 
  # unite the columns 
  unite(rows, index, max_row, sep = "-")
    # A tibble: 10 x 5
      r2 distance  rows   mean_r2 diff_of_distance
 * <dbl>    <int> <chr>     <dbl>            <int>
 1 33.64    67866   1-5 17.860000            75527
 2  8.50    77229   2-5 13.915000            66164
 3 15.07   109119   3-6 13.842500            68551
 4 24.35   142279   4-7 13.140000            74161
 5  7.74   143393   5-7  9.403333            73047
 6  8.21   177670   6-8 11.043333            76081
 7 12.26   216440   7-9 17.076667            66116
 8 12.66   253751  8-10 26.016667            67065
 9 26.31   282556  9-10 32.695000            38260
10 39.08   320816 10-10 39.080000                0
```

This works because group_by subsets the dataframe, thus you can access within `mutate` the respective `distance` value per group and calculate the difference with the complete vector using `.$distance` as this access the complete column regardless the `group_by()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am currently trying it but it's running since 10 minutes. Maybe the for loop is not appropriate for the size of this data frame (see edit 1). Any other suggestions? Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: Please see my edits. I totally revised the code and switched to a solution using dplyr. Should be very fast also for hugh data sets.